# How can I set up a connection to Redis Sentinel using Jedis library?

Tags: java, redis, jedis, sentinel

How do I set up a connection to a Redis Sentinel server/cluster using the Jedis library?

Answer (score 20):

The Jedis library is an awesome solution, but unfortunately with bad documentation.

So,

```java
@Autowired private JedisSentinelPool pool;

public void mymethod() {
    Jedis jedis = null;
    try {
        jedis = pool.getResource();
        jedis.hset(....
    } catch (JedisException je) {
        throw je;
    } finally {
        if (jedis != null) pool.returnResource(jedis);
    }
}
```

As I am using Spring, I need:

```xml
<bean id="redisSentinel" class="redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool">
<constructor-arg index="0" value="mymaster" />
<constructor-arg index="1">
     <set>
         <value>hostofsentinel:26379</value>
    </set>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg index="2" ref="jedisPoolConfig"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: how to use this for RedisTemplate?

Comment: You can use RedisTemplate as the example i shared for this post

Comment: Can someone explain why JedisSentinelPool.getResource() doesn't return JedisSentinel but return Jedis instead?

Comment: @Ray Wu, because you aren't interacting with the sentinel, but rather the redis master that the sentinels track for you.  The sentinels just track which masters are available so you can talk to them.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example when you aren't using Spring and need a simple connection via Jedis to a Redis master/slave set managed by Redis sentinels

```java
public class JedisTestSentinelEndpoint {
    private static final String MASTER_NAME = "mymaster";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "foobared";
    private static final Set sentinels;
    static {
        sentinels = new HashSet();
        sentinels.add("mymaster-0.servers.example.com:26379");
        sentinels.add("mymaster-1.servers.example.com:26379");
        sentinels.add("mymaster-2.servers.example.com:26379");
    }

    public JedisTestSentinelEndpoint() {
    }

    private void runTest() throws InterruptedException {
        JedisSentinelPool pool = new JedisSentinelPool(MASTER_NAME, sentinels);
        Jedis jedis = null;
            try {
                printer("Fetching connection from pool");
                jedis = pool.getResource();
                printer("Authenticating...");
                jedis.auth(PASSWORD);
                printer("auth complete...");
                Socket socket = jedis.getClient().getSocket();
                printer("Connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                printer("Writing...");
                jedis.set("java-key-999", "java-value-999");
                printer("Reading...");
                jedis.get("java-key-999");
            } catch (JedisException e) {
                printer("Connection error of some sort!");
                printer(e.getMessage());
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } finally {
                if (jedis != null) {
                    jedis.close();
                }
            }
    }
...
}
```

Source: [This blog post](https://scalegrid.io/blog/high-availability-with-redis-sentinels-connecting-to-redis-masterslave-sets/) on connecting to Redis Sentinels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Redisson](https://redisson.org)? It offer sentinel automatic master/slave/sentinel discovery and topology update and you don't need to handle with connections, data encoding... it's all done by Redisson. Here is the code example:

```java
Config config = new Config();
config.useSentinelServers()
   .setMasterName("mymaster")
   .addSentinelAddress("127.0.0.1:26389", "127.0.0.1:26379")

RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);

RMap<MyKey, MyValue> map = redisson.getMap("myMap");
map.put(new MyKey(), new MyValue());
```

Comment: How could I apply different Redis operations using Radisson, apart from put and get?

Comment: @VeswanthRaju Here is a documentation how Redis command mapped to Redisson object https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping