# Does Spring Data Redis (1.3.2.RELEASE) support JedisSentinelPool of jedis?

Tags: java, spring, redis, sentinel, spring-data-redis

Does Spring Data Redis (1.3.2.RELEASE) support JedisSentinelPool of jedis?

Maybe it doesn't support,who will give me an answer?

If it doesn't support,how should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382065/looking-for-an-example-of-jedis-with-sentinel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for Redis Sentinel is added to Spring Data Redis 1.4. It will be in the upcoming [Evans RC1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Evans), allowing configuration of `JedisConnectionFactory` to make use of `JedisSentinelPool`.

```
RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
  .master("mymaster")
  .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26379)
  .sentinel("127.0.0.1", 26380);

JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
factory.afterPropertiesSet();
```

You can already have a look at the current snapshot build:

```
compile(group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-redis', version: '1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
```

Comment: @Christoph Strobl, can you explain this? What are the configuration params with simple configuration?

Presently I am using 3 redis sentinels with one master and one slave redis instance. How do i configure the same?