# how to connect multiple redis instances through spring data redis?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to connect multiple redis instances via spring. But I did not find any documentation.

Here is how I am using it currently. I am using Jedis as the client and I plan on using Jedis only as I might require support for sentinel.

```
<bean id="jedisConnFactory"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory">
    <property name ="hostName" value ="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="6379" />   
</bean>

<bean id="stringRedisSerializer"
    class="org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer" />

<!-- redis template definition -->
<bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
    p:connection-factory-ref="jedisConnFactory" 
    p:keySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
    p:hashKeySerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer"
    p:ValueSerializer-ref="stringRedisSerializer" />
```

I want to add multiple redis instances to the connection pool. Like..

```
<property name ="hosts" value ="localhost:6379,localhost:6380"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching , I found, there is no support for client side partitioning currently in spring-data-redis.

In future the partitioning technique in redis shall move to redis-cluster permanently.

At present, To use partition along with spring-data-redis, the best way is to use twemproxy and point JedisConnectionFactory host and port to twemproxy.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for support of `JedisSentinelPool` then have a look at [does-spring-data-redis-1-3-2-release-support-jedissentinelpool-of-jedis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131166/does-spring-data-redis-1-3-2-release-support-jedissentinelpool-of-jedis/25146637#25146637).

Comment: Yes spring redis supports sentinel. But currently only Jedis supports Redis Sentinel. Hence I want to use Jedis as the underlying library. But that's now that I am asking for.