# redis cluster url notation in configuration

Tags: redis, configuration, cluster-computing, openstack

What's the supposedly commonly used notation for accessing a redis cluster URL in a linux config file? A regular such URL looks something like

```
 url = redis://<password>@<ip>:<port>
```

so an example would be

```
url = redis://secret@1.2.3.4:6379
```

Trying that out on a cluster gets cryptic errors

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: MOVED 6553 <newip>:<port>
tooz.ToozError
```

But I can't find, anywhere on the internet, what to do if you have more than one node. The documentation refers to something called 'sentinel' and suggests doing something like;

```
url = redis://<ip>:<sentinel port>?sentinel=<master name>&sentinel_fallback=<ip2>:<sentinel port>&<sentinel_fallback>=<ip3>:<sentinel port>
```

which seems patently absurd. Where's the password? (Hint: this just produces 'permission denied' as-is) What in the world is the "master name"? It does not make any sense. There's N instances (with N = XY, where X is our number of replicas, X >= 2, and Y is the number of shards, Y >= 3), resulting in N >= 6. There's at least 3 nodes, so at least 3 sentinels. Each instance has its own 'name', so there's 6 of those master names. Wildly guessing that  can be replaced by @ and using that gets me even more cryptic errors.

```
tooz.coordination.ToozConnectionError: No master found for <name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Tooz Redis Driver](https://docs.openstack.org/tooz/latest/user/drivers.html#redis) only supports Redis Sentinel.

The actual [driver source](https://docs.openstack.org/tooz/latest/_modules/tooz/drivers/redis.html) code states:

> ```
> - Consistent, note that this is still restricted to only
>   one redis server, without the recently released redis (alpha)
>   clustering > 1 server will not be consistent when partitions
>   or failures occur (even redis clustering docs state it is
>   not a fully AP or CP solution, which means even with it there
>   will still be *potential* inconsistencies).
> - Master/slave failover (when setup with redis `sentinel`_), giving
>   some notion of HA (values *can* be lost when a failover transition
>   occurs).
> ```

You are trying to use [Redis Cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial), in which case you can have only the primary as connected host.

The error message you got `MOVED 6553` is saying that the key you tried to access is in another primary (in an other shard).

Redis Cluster clients usually require only one host:port to be pointed to, and they use [`CLUSTER SLOTS`](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-slots) command to discover the cluster topology. This is not implemented in the Tooz Driver.

Consider switching to [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) if you have to use Tooz and require high availability.

Here is more on [Redis sentinel vs clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143072/redis-sentinel-vs-clustering)